# Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Schemes_Manager' not found

Tags: wordpress

I have a Little Dino theme.
I updated elementor to the latest version and unfortunately I get the error Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor \ Schemes_Manager' not found in /home/platne/serwer37442/public_html/wp-content/plugins/littledino-core1111/includes/elementor/init.php:422 Stack trace: # 0

does anyone know where the problem lies? :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens, because Elementor deprecated its Schemes_Manager class:
https://developers.elementor.com/v3-6-planned-deprecations/

In themeforest, at a different codepart this issue was addressed by the theme's developer already:
https://themeforest.net/item/littledino-modern-kids-wordpress-theme/24525614/comments?page=1&filter=all#comment_26854919

so an update on your theme and its core plugin should solve the problem.